# Set VLC Playback Rate through HTTP Interface

Tags: http, video, vlc

I am trying to make an easy-to-use remote control for VLC that can set both the video to be played and the rate at which it will be played.

I know that to set the video to be played, the HTTP command is `http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml?command=in_play&input=video_to_play`.

I know also that to play, pause, and toggle repeat the commands are, respectively, `?command=pl_play`, `?command=pl_pause`, and `?command=pl_repeat`.

However, I do not know how to set the playback speed. I expected it to be something like `?command=pl_rate&input=<rate>` or `?command=rate&input=<rate>` or `?command=in_rate&input=<rate>`.

I can see the following just by going to `http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml`:

```
<root>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <aspectratio>default</aspectratio>
    ... other settings
    <rate>1</rate>
    ... other settings
</root>
```

so I know that rate is a value that the HTTP interface knows about.

How do I set it with an HTTP command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to give up on setting the rate at runtime through the `HTTP` interface. Instead, what I had to do was start `VLC` with command-line arguments specifying the rate for each individual movie, like so:

```
vlc [arguments] video1 :rate=[rate] video2 :rate=[rate] video3 :rate=[rate] ...
```